# Shrink and expand of homothetic gradient Ricci soliton

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

For a homothetic gradient Ricci soliton, 
$$
R_{ij}+\nabla_i\nabla_jf-\lambda g_{ij}=0
$$
Why for $\lambda>0$ the soliton is shrinking? Why for $\lambda <0$ it is expanding ?

Comment: Think about flat space, then the equation is just $\Delta f=\lambda$. Then we have solutions that are $\lambda(\sum_i x_i^2)$, up to a harmonic function. If our space is compact though, these are constant, so we see the behavoir. In general the behavoir follows from the general theory, since the equation is just $Lf=\lambda g$, where $L$ is the conformal laplacian.

Comment: @Chanler Whether the compact makes the $\sum_i x_i^2$ only has finite $x_i\neq 0$?

Comment: Im sorry, I didn't understand that. Care to repeat?

Comment: @Chanler  I want to know  why we need the space is compact.   If  the space is compact ,will the $\lambda(\sum_i x_i^2)$ be convergent  or finite ?

Comment: Oh! Well, the problem then can be even seen in flat space. The solution space of $\Delta f=0$ contains the real parts of any holomorphic function! So in particular things like $e^xsin(y)+e^ysin(x)$, which causes the behavoir of your function to be obscured. I was just using if as an example, since on the compact space the reasoning for this notation is less opaque.

Comment: It is very important to note that this is a notation, not a definition. And as a notation, it is based on intution based on examples like the above. There is substance to it, but because of degenerate examples like above, it has much greater substance on compact spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First think of $f = 0$. Then the equation becomes

$$R_{ij} = \lambda g_{ij}.$$

That is, $M$ is an Einstein manifold. In this case if we apply the Ricci flow 
$$\partial_t g_{ij,t} = -2 R_{ij,t}$$
to $M$, then one can guess the solution by setting
$$g_{ij,t} = \lambda(t) g_{ij,0}, $$
then 
$$\partial_t g_{ij,t} = \lambda'(t) g_{ij,0}$$ 
and 
$$-2R_{ij,t} = -2 R_{ij,0} = -2\lambda g_{ij,0}.$$
Thus the Ricci flow equation is the same as
$$\lambda'(t) = -2\lambda, \ \ \ \ \lambda(0) = 1.$$
Solving this ODE gives

$$\lambda(t) = -2\lambda t +1.$$
Thus the solution to the Ricci flow (if $M$ is Einstein) is 
$$ g_{ij,t}= ( -2\lambda t +1) g_{ij}.$$
Thus when $\lambda >0$, $\lambda(t)$ is decreasing and so $M$ is shrinking. When $\lambda <0$, $\lambda(t) $ is increasing and so $M$ is called expanding.

Now go back to the general situation where $f$ is not constant. Then (at least when $M$ is compact) one can apply the Deturck's trick to see that if you apply Ricci flow to $M$, then the solution $\bar g_{ij,t}$ is 
$$\bar g_{ij,t} = \lambda(t) \phi_t^* g_{ij}.$$
So up to a diffeomorphism, the metric is shrinking (if $\lambda >0$) and expanding (if $\lambda <0$).

Comment: Thanks ,but I think the $\lambda(0)=1$, besides ,where can I get information about Deturck's trick ?

Comment: @lanse2pty You are right (edited). That Deturck trick can be found in almost all textbook on Ricci flow I guess. Or actually in his short paper: Deforming metrics in the direction of their Ricci tensors. J. Differential Geom. 18 (1983), no. 1, 157–162

Comment: @Joho Ma   I need your help.  it is my new question. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487398/why-the-partial-t-gamma-ipk-gamma-jlp-gamma-jpk-gamma-ilp-va