# Why the $\partial_t(\Gamma_{ip}^k \Gamma_{jl}^p -\Gamma_{jp}^k\Gamma_{il}^p)$ vanish?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

In the red line part of below picture  ,why the $\partial_t(\Gamma_{ip}^k  \Gamma_{jl}^p  -\Gamma_{jp}^k\Gamma_{il}^p)$ vanish ?I know $\Gamma$ will vanish under normal coordinate. But if so, the RHS of red line will equal to $0$. And there is similar question in $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Gamma_{jl}^h$ of the third  line above red line .

Thanks for any useful hint or answer. And the below picture is from 183th page of the [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term

$$\tag{1} \partial_t(\Gamma_{ip}^k  \Gamma_{jl}^p  -\Gamma_{jp}^k\Gamma_{il}^p)$$

is not the same as the term

$$\tag{2} \partial_t \Gamma_{ip}^k .$$

The first one is zero at $x$. Because you have to apply **product rule** to this term, and after that, all terms will have an zeroth order term $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ there, so they are all zero at $x$ under normal coordinate. However, you don't have a zeroth order term on $(2)$.