# How to prove the expanding Ricci soliton is Einstein metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow, soliton-theory

As picture below ,I want to prove the expanding Ricci soliton is Einstein metric.

I can get $R+\Delta f-n\lambda=0$. Besides ,I want to prove $R+|\nabla f|^2= C$ for some constant $C$. But fail. I just get $R+|\nabla f|^2-2\lambda f=C'$.

So, how to do it ? Just give a little hint is enough . Thanks.

Picture below is from the 176 page of [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ajm/1154098947). And, the definition of expanding Ricci soliton can be found in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482795/shrink-and-expand-of-homothetic-gradient-ricci-soliton).

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R_{ij} + \nabla_i\nabla_j f= k g_{ij},\ k<0$ so that $$R+\Delta
f=kn$$ And since $\nabla g=0$ by a same calculation in steady case
we have $$R+|\nabla f|^2=2kf+C$$ Hence we have $$
 \Delta
f-|\nabla f|^2=k(n-2f)-C$$ That is $$ \int (n-2f(x_0) -C/k)e^{-f}
\leq \int (n-2f -C/k)e^{-f}=0$$ where $f(x_0)\geq f(x)$

Note that $2kf(x_0)+C=R(x_0)\geq kn$ Hence $$ n-2f-\frac{C}{k}=0
$$

Comment: By the same calculation in steady case, I get $R+|\nabla f|^2-2\lambda f=C$. If you know how to get $R+|\nabla f|^2=C$, could you give a detail process? Thanks very much.

Comment: Why does this argument not work for shrinking solitons?